# Page is white-screening due to weird problem

Tags: php, oop

I have these three functions inside the same class:

```
public function checkLogin() {
    if(isset($this->getSessionVal())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

public function getSessionVal($type = 'user') {
    return $this->sanitise($_SESSION[$type]);
}

public function sanitise($input) {
    $input = trim($input);

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
         $input = stripslashes($input);
    }

    if($this->conn) {
        $input = mysql_real_escape_string($input);  
    }

    $input = strip_tags($input);

    return $input;
}
```

When I use the above it white-screens and prints nothing, so typically a syntax error, but it's not syntax (Dreamweaver doesn't show up any, and I'm sure it's not. If I change checkLogin to the following:

```
public function checkLogin() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The sanitise function is fine, I took that out of getSessionVal and it still white-screeened. I'm completely confused, to me it makes no sense so I have someone has an idea (I know I could do it the way it works, but I want to understand why this doesn't work).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: look in your server's error log

Comment: As a side note, I'm not sure whether what your code is doing to the session variables makes sense. It is likely to over-sanitize and break data. I would recommend sanitizing stuff only before it is used, with the method necessary for that specific use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(isset($this->getSessionVal())) {
```

[`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) is a language construct. You can not pass it a function call as a parameter.

Activate error reporting - you should get an error message.

As a workaround, you could e.g. have `getSessionVal()` return `false` if the session variable was not set. (That is if `false` is not a possible value of what you are returning, of course.)

You would then move the `isset` into `getSessionVal()` , and test for `false` in `checkLogin()`.

Comment: That's the weird thing, I used `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and nothing was output, just a white screen.

Comment: @Ashley strange, I thought I remembered PHP breaks loudly over this. It could be treating it as a syntax error, though.

Comment: @Pekka I can't use any function like that? I tried empty() (out of curiousity) and that didn't work either... I assumed passing the value of a variable to empty() would be fine, but I guess not.

Comment: @Ashley `isset()` and `empty()` both happen to be language constructs where this kind of thing doesn't work. In any other function, it will

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `isset()` when calling the other method in the class.

```
public function checkLogin() {
    if($this->getSessionVal()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```